Формула подсчета пропорции стороны
Ширина:352
Высота:198
Необходимо изменить ширину в большую либо в меньшую сторону, какова при этом будет высота?
Аналогично с высотой, изменяем высоту, какова будет ширина?

Во сколько раз изменился один размер, во столько же раз меняем другой размер

Гуглить по слову "пропорция" )

Если правильно помню из уроков школьной математики то как-то так
Высчитываем пропорциональное соотношение высоты к ширине:
352/198 = 1,777777778

получается, что на каждые прибавляющиеся/убавляющиеся 1,77 пикселя ширины, Вы должны добавить/убавить 1 пиксель высоты. Ну и в обратную сторону. Так как мы учитываем только два знака после запятой, то конечно при больших размерах будет набегать погрешность, но думаю ею можно принебречь.

На полученное соотношение нужно умножить или разделить. Кто это мы и почему мы учитываем 2 знака после запятой? Ну и может функцию на JS, а не только слова?
